# SSR in linear regression

Tags: statistics

I need to show that $SSR = \hat\beta_1'X_cX_c'\beta_1$, where:
$X_c$ is a centered matrix $X_1: X= (\mathbb 1_n, X_1)$ and $\hat\beta_1$ is a OLS estimation (without $\hat\beta_0$).

Well, I have a hard time finding a good approach to this example. I tried putting $X_c=(I-\frac{1}{n}J)X_1$ but it really hasn't helped me a lot. Shall I start with $SSR = \sum_1^n(\hat y-\bar y)^2 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regression line $\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1 X_1$ always passes through the point $(\bar{Y},\bar{X}_1)$ (here $\bar{X}_1$ is a row vector) so that
$$
\hat{Y}-1_n\bar{Y}=1_n\hat{\beta}_0+X_1\hat{\beta}_1-1_n\hat{\beta}_0-(1_n\bar{X}_1)\hat{\beta}_1=X_c\hat{\beta}_0
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{SSR}=(\hat{Y}-1_n\bar{Y})^{\top}(\hat{Y}-1_n\bar{Y})=(X_c\hat{\beta}_1)^{\top}X_c\hat{\beta}_1.
$$

Comment: thanks! could you also please explain why this line should pass through the point $(\bar Y, \bar X_1)$?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/regression-proof-that-the-point-of-averages-x-y-lies-on-the-estimated-regressi